# Oneboxing is broken with the new blog

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, blog, onebox

Good news: [we have a new blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/07/the-new-stack-exchange-blog/)!

Bad news: this [kinda broke oneboxing](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3646980#3646980)...

Can chat be updated to accommodate for the new blog?

Comment: ooo, shiny. And not WordPress!

Comment: Working on it now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chat has been updated to correctly onebox our new blog.

Example: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3648206#3648206